# Matlab Codegen build error

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder

I am trying to convert the below Matlab code into C++ using codegen. However it fails at build and I get the error:

> "??? Unless 'rows' is specified, the first input must be a vector. If the vector is variable-size, the either the first dimension or the second must have a fixed length of 1. The input [] is not supported. Use a 1-by-0 or 0-by-1 input (e.g., zeros(1,0) or zeros(0,1)) to represent the empty set."

It then points to [id,m,n] = unique(id); being the culprit. Why doesn't it build and what's the best way to fix it?

```
function [L,num,sz] = label(I,n) %#codegen

% Check input arguments
error(nargchk(1,2,nargin));
if nargin==1, n=8; end

assert(ndims(I)==2,'The input I must be a 2-D array')

sizI = size(I);
id = reshape(1:prod(sizI),sizI);
sz = ones(sizI);

% Indexes of the adjacent pixels
vec = @(x) x(:);
if n==4 % 4-connected neighborhood
idx1 = [vec(id(:,1:end-1)); vec(id(1:end-1,:))];
idx2 = [vec(id(:,2:end)); vec(id(2:end,:))];
elseif n==8 % 8-connected neighborhood
idx1 = [vec(id(:,1:end-1)); vec(id(1:end-1,:))];
idx2 = [vec(id(:,2:end)); vec(id(2:end,:))];
idx1 = [idx1; vec(id(1:end-1,1:end-1)); vec(id(2:end,1:end-1))];
idx2 = [idx2; vec(id(2:end,2:end)); vec(id(1:end-1,2:end))];
else
error('The second input argument must be either 4 or 8.')
end

% Create the groups and merge them (Union/Find Algorithm)
for k = 1:length(idx1)
root1 = idx1(k);
root2 = idx2(k);

while root1~=id(root1)
id(root1) = id(id(root1));
root1 = id(root1);
end
while root2~=id(root2)
id(root2) = id(id(root2));
root2 = id(root2);
end

if root1==root2, continue, end
% (The two pixels belong to the same group)

N1 = sz(root1); % size of the group belonging to root1
N2 = sz(root2); % size of the group belonging to root2

if I(root1)==I(root2) % then merge the two groups
if N1 < N2
    id(root1) = root2;
    sz(root2) = N1+N2;
else
    id(root2) = root1;
    sz(root1) = N1+N2;
end
end
end

while 1
id0 = id;
id = id(id);
if isequal(id0,id), break, end
end
sz = sz(id);

% Label matrix
isNaNI = isnan(I);
id(isNaNI) = NaN;
[id,m,n] = unique(id);
I = 1:length(id);
L = reshape(I(n),sizI);
L(isNaNI) = 0;

if nargout>1, num = nnz(~isnan(id)); end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, if you are using MATLAB R2013b or newer, you can replace `error(nargchk(1,2,nargin))` with `narginchk(1,2)`.

As the error message says, for codegen `unique` requires that the input be a vector unless 'rows' is passed.

If you look at the report (click the "Open report" link that is shown) and hover over id you will likely see that its size is neither `1-by-N` nor `N-by-1`. The requirement for `unique` can be seen if you search for `unique` here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html

You could do one of a few things:

Make `id` a vector and treat it as a vector for the computation. Instead of the declaration:

```
id = reshape(1:prod(sizI),sizI);
```

you could use:

```
id = 1:numel(I)
```

Then `id` would be a row vector.

You could also keep the code as is and do something like:

```
[idtemp,m,n] = unique(id(:));
id = reshape(idtemp,size(id));
```

Obviously, this will cause a copy, `idtemp`, to be made but it may involve fewer changes to your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the anonymous function stored in the variable `vec` and make `vec` a subfunction:

   ```
   function y = vec(x)
   coder.inline('always');
   y = x(:);
   ```
2. Without the `'rows'` option, the input to the `unique` function is always interpreted as a vector, and the output is always a vector, anyway.  So, for example, something like `id = unique(id)` would have the effect of `id = id(:)` if all the elements of the matrix `id` were unique.  There is no harm in making the input a vector going in.  So change the line

   ```
   [id,m,n] = unique(id);
   ```

to

```
    [id,m,n] = unique(id(:));
```